# Why isn't my cron job going?

Tags: cron

I was told that to get a cron job running hourly you simply have to put a shell script into `/etc/cron.hourly`

So I tried adding

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
firefox www.superuser.com
```

Into a file `test.sh` and putting it into `/etc/cron.hourly/` directory.  Then I `chown` it to root and `chmod +x` on it.  It does as expected if I execute it directly.  But it doesn't execute automatically, hourly.. what am I missing?

---

*edit:*
I've changed the script to something simpler, just

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo foo > ~/sandpit/bar.txt
```

Then I waited an hour , these are the last 4 lines at the end of my `/var/log/syslog`

```
Nov  1 18:45:01 wim-ubuntu ntpdate[1719]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.149832 sec
Nov  1 18:46:27 wim-ubuntu kernel: [  106.562460] exe (2058): /proc/2058/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/2058/oom_score_adj instead.
Nov  1 19:17:01 wim-ubuntu CRON[4204]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov  1 20:17:01 wim-ubuntu CRON[4793]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

But my file isn't being created, so I guess my cron job still isn't going.

---

*edit2:*

I removed the extensions, now I have the scripts actually found by cron.  But they are failing for unknown reasons (details below)

```
wim@wim-ubuntu:/etc/cron.hourly$ ll
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-11-02 01:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x 150 root root 12288 2011-11-02 01:58 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   102 2011-09-20 10:04 .placeholder
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    49 2011-11-01 19:00 test*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    48 2011-11-01 19:23 test2*
wim@wim-ubuntu:/etc/cron.hourly$ run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.hourly/test
/etc/cron.hourly/test2
wim@wim-ubuntu:/etc/cron.hourly$ date
Wed Nov  2 02:25:39 EST 2011
wim@wim-ubuntu:/etc/cron.hourly$ cat test
#!/usr/bin/env sh
firefox www.stackoverflow.com

wim@wim-ubuntu:/etc/cron.hourly$ cat test2
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo foo > ~/sandpit/bar.txt

wim@wim-ubuntu:/etc/cron.hourly$ tail -4 /var/log/syslog
Nov  2 02:01:33 wim-ubuntu AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested
Nov  2 02:17:01 wim-ubuntu CRON[8249]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov  2 02:17:01 wim-ubuntu CRON[8248]: (CRON) error (grandchild #8249 failed with exit status 1)
Nov  2 02:17:01 wim-ubuntu CRON[8248]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: It's probably executing and failing as its a graphical program. Have you considered writing to. File instead for testing? Also, you could try your user account's personal crontab

Comment: Check your syslog. If the job was executed, cron logs that.

Comment: Do you have a `sandpit` directory in root's home directory where the cronjob can write its `bar.txt` file?

Comment: yes, i created the directory first

Comment: Why are you using `#!/usr/bin/env sh` rather than `#!/bin/sh`?  It's far more likely that `env` isn't in `/usr/bin/` than that `sh` isn't in `/bin`.

Comment: it's off-topic, but: this line was recommended to me elsewhere and i've gotten into the habit of using it.  i believe it allows to use whatever shell the user has specified in their env, which may or may not be the same as /bin/sh ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure why my jobs in /etc/cron.hourly don't run.  But I was able to schedule them in an alternate way by adding them manually with the command `crontab -e`.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of cron don't run scripts with file name extensions so try renaming the script (eg: mv test.sh test).

You can probably check what cron will run using this test (it doesn't actually run the files):

```
run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly
```

Comment: it seems you were right about the extensions, my scripts are at least recognised by cron now.  but they aren't running properly.  if i remove the --test and use run-parts /etc/cron.hourly they seem to run ok